# External function not being passed properly to IIFE -

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, addeventlistener

Pretty noob question.

I have an event listener function where I'm doing some DOM manipulation. It looks like this:

```
(function(){
  $('.js-service-more-close').on('click', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var service = self.closest('.service-more').prev('.service');
    var figures = self.closest('.service-more-inner-bar').next('.service-more-inner').find('figure');
    self.closest('.service-more').removeClass('service-more--is-expanded').css('max-height', 0);
    service.removeClass('service--is-active');
    figures.removeClass('fade-in');
  });
 })();
```

It works fine.

I thought I'd extract the manipulations into another function so I can reuse them elsewhere. I now have this.

```
var closeItUp = function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var service = self.closest('.service-more').prev('.service');
  var figures = self.closest('.service-more-inner-bar').next('.service-more-inner').find('figure');
  self.closest('.service-more').removeClass('service-more--is-expanded').css('max-height', 0);
  service.removeClass('service--is-active');
  figures.removeClass('fade-in');
};

(function(){
  $('.js-service-more-close').on('click', function() {
    closeItUp();
  });
})();
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why. There are no obvious console errors.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, since you are not passing a function to an IIFE anywhere. You simply lost the `this` object when moving code outside the relevant closure for it, but the function itself does get called.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @Mtz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `this` is not the one you expect, you lost it when you moved the function in another closure (`window` in this case). Propagate it like so:

```
(function(){
  $('.js-service-more-close').on('click', function() {
    closeItUp.call(this);
  });
})();
```

...or, even better:

```
(function(){
  $('.js-service-more-close').on('click', closeItUp);
})();
```

This way, the `closeItUp` function will get the correct `this` object from `jQuery` and your selectors will work properly.

Comment: I can't up vote your answer due to low rep, but you nailed it! Thanks!

Comment: You can accept the answer as the correct one though ;) glad i could help!